# Окно в нижний правый угол

Tags: extjs

Как поместить окно в ExtJS в нижний правый угол?

Comment: Прошу прощения у сообщества, но другого способа, как связаться здесь с человеком, я не знаю. К сожалению, личных сообщений на сайте нет.

Андрей, если вас интересует халтура по профессии (работа с частичной занятостью то биш), пожалуйста, напишите на hr@soft-in.ru. Буду рад общению:). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [`alignTo();`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Floating-method-alignTo). [Вот тут](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-alignTo) описание аббревиатур для позиционирования.

[Пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/A8paQ/)

```
var window1 = Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
  title: 'Окно в углу' ,
  width: 250 ,
  height: 180 ,
  html: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... viverra scelerisque.' ,
  modal: true
});

window1.show();
window1.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'br-br');
```